# Calcultions to choose between a transistor (switch)

Tags: arduino, transistors, control

thanks in advance :).

I am a little bit confused, i need to turn on a led lamp (5watts), using a light sensor from my Arduino. I was reading a lot of theory the past two days. Here is the deal:

What i understand is the next:

To choose the transistor i need the current, voltages and pose consumption of the load. And also i need to limit the current to the load from the source and put a resistance from the arduino too.

1st: I need a lamp of 5 watts(led lamp).
2nd: I have a 12 volt battery at 7A/H.
3rd: My arduino gives me 5V and 40mA.

Since i need 5watss i can find the current to turn on my lamp using P=IV. 5W/12V=.416amperes.
Then i need to limit the current from the source, if i have 7A, i need to waste (eat 6.5 Amperes). I Find a resistance capable if this using I=V/R, R=V/I, R=12V/6.5A, R= 1.84 ohms (or 2 ohms).

Then i got the resistance from my load at my input. Now i need to find a transistor supporting that values and the resistance from the base to my arduino. How i do that?.

I Know the currents must be additive then IB+IC=IE, since i know how many current i have from IC and IB i can use kirchoff laws to find the resistance from my arduino.

IB+IC=IE, then IB=IE-IC, then VB/RB=IE-IC but then IB and the associated values VB and RB depend on the transistor?, finding a model of transistor i find how many current i need to swicht some current from C and the i need to couple that current from the data sheet with a resistance to switch the arduino?.

I am missing something? or i am wrong at everything? :S

Comment: You forgot to take hfe into account. You don't need to burn current if the LED lamp is rated for a specific voltage already. You need to subtract the Vf of the LED and Vce of the transistor. You need a transistor that not only can sustain the current, it also needs to be able to dissipate the resultant power.

Comment: A battery rated at 7 Ampere-Hours can theoretically deliver 7 amps for 1 hour, 1 amp for 7 hours or .416 amps for 16.8 hours, before being fully discharged.  You do not need to "burn up" 6.5 amps to keep the battery happy - it will only deliver what your load requires.

Comment: i was seraching for a led lamp ( i found one at 12V and 5 watts ) o it meets the battery values. Maybe the question now is if i can adapt a led lamp (hand lamp) and make it work with the lightsensor.

It is very useful what you tell me, because then i can attach a load and only the arduino will need a resistence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best bet is to use the following:  Connect your bulb to your 12 volt source in series with your resistor, which is in series with your transistor (Collector side on an NPN BJT).  Then connect an arduino pin, in series with a resistor, to the base junction.  Finally, connect your Emitter to ground.  The problem with your calculation is that it assumes all of your voltage is being dropped across your bulb.  You can't do this, because you'd need current to flow through the circuit, which means you'll need to add a resistor, which will take a voltage drop of its own (V=IR).  Your best bet is to find the right balance between the voltage drop that you need across your bulb, and across your resistor.  As an example, if you drop 10 Volts across the bulb, this means to generate 5W, you'll need to limit your current to 500mA (P = IV).  This leaves 2 Volts that can be dropped across the resistor, giving you a 4 Ohm resistor.  Also keep in mind: the resistor you choose will need to be power rated appropriately (in the example I used, it needs to be rated for 1 W), and you'll want to make sure that the transistor can handle the appropriate power dissipation.  For most BJTs with a high enough Beta value, your Emitter and Collector currents should be equal, so I wouldn't worry too much about any voltage drop across the transistor.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Since the OP uses the term "5 W LED Lamp", I suspect that he has an LED assembly that is designed to operate directly from 12 volts, so he won't need to worry about a current limiting resistor, as you would with bare LEDs.  If the LED lamp is not designed to work from 12 volts, then he has to worry about adapting it to work from his 12 volt battery.  In any case, we need a little more info about his LED lamp before we can fully specify a solution for him.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but as he stipulated that he wanted/needed a transistor for control, I'm having a hard time buying that he wouldn't need a current limiting resistor.  If the transistor is "on," that 12V source is going to see a (nearly) direct connection to ground - still no need for resistance?  I'd still be interested to see what he says in regards to spec though.

Comment: Mi light bulb is like this one: http://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-447056149-mini-foco-led-12v-luz-blanca-o-calida-rosca-e27-5-watts-_JM

Comment: Anoterh case i think will be:

Use a hand led lamp and adapt that lamp to a desklapm using the arduino as controler. Then as everyone says i do not need a esistence because the poser consumption will be just the power used by the lamp.

If i use the house installation then i will need a relay or a resistence, i am wrong?

Comment: I don't understand Spanish, but it appears that the lamp in your link is intended to operate directly from 12 volts, so you won't need a current-limiting resistor.  Despite zklim's comment, you can control the lamp with a transistor (rated for 0.5 amp or more) without a resistor in series with the lamp.  You will still need a resistor between the Arduino output and the transistor base.

Comment: I hate my keyboard :(:

Another case i am thinking: Use a handed led lamp and adapt that lamp to a desk lamp, using the arduino as controler. Then as everyone says i do not need a resistence because the power consumption will be just the power used by the lamp. If i use the house installation then i will need a relay or a resistence, i am wrong?